# Fetch all records from multiple tables without using DTO/POJO classes

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-jdbc

I need to fetch all records from multiple table of Oracle data-base without using any DTO/POJO classes by query in spring boot.

have a separate table in which, Table-Name and Primery-Key will be available with reference of these record need  fetch from different tables records from Oracle Data-Base.

and not to have any impact of data types changes of fields.

which is good either JDBC/HIBERNATE/JPA.

if any references or examples will be appreciated.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: do you know Entitymanager#createNativeQuery. I would stay with JPA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.